# Who are the (highborn) prisoners held in King's Landing throughout the War of the Five Kings?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I know that Sansa Stark was held captive after Eddard Stark's execution and that Horas/Hobber Redwyne are held to ensure the good behavior of their father, but is there anyone else?

Too keep the answer from becoming too exhaustive, limiting it to only named characters would be preferable (e.g. any living Stark soldiers held alongside Sansa need not be mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prisoners

The following characters were literally held prisoners in the Red Fortress dungeons, the Black Cells:

- **[Eddard Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Eddard_Stark)**

  Eddard was arrested for treason and held in the Black Cells, when the  War of the Five Kings was already started. He was executed shortly after his release.
- **[Grand Maester Pycelle](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pycelle)**

  He was imprisoned by Tyrion, after he confronted him about his many schemes and treasons against the Realm. He was released after a short time by Cersei.
- **[Tyrion Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_Lannister)**

  Tyrion himself was held captive in the Black Cells before his trial, being suspected of the murder of Joffrey at the Purple Wedding. He escaped after the trial and fled to Essos.
- **[Falyse Stokeworth](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Falyse_Stokeworth)**

  She was given by Cersei to Qyburn to perform his experiments; she was held captive in the Black Cells too, that <strike>Dr. Frankenstein</strike> Qyburn used as his own laboratory. She died there by the sufferings caused by the tortures.

## Hostages

The following characters were held hostages, to all effects captives, even if formally and legally they were not considered prisoners:

- **[Sansa Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sansa_Stark)**

  She was held hostage a weapon against Lannister's enemy Houses, until she was taken out of King's Landing by The Hound.
- **[Horas Redwyne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Horas_Redwyne)**

  He was held in King's Landing along with his twin, Hobber, to ensure his father's good behavior. Eventually released due to the alliance between the Tyrells and the Lannisters.
- **[Hobber Redwyne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hobber_Redwyne)**

  He was held in King's Landing along with his twin, Horas, to ensure his father's good behavior. Sent along with Littlefinger as a show of good faith when the man goes to negotiate with the Tyrells.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the hostage vs prisoner situation. In my wording of the question, it never occurred to me to specify which I was looking for